# Can not connect Database to

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm trying to connect my server to MS SQL Server Studio but keep on getting an error. On this [post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/128672/can-not-connect-to-hp-sqlexpress) I saw that I can use PowerShell to get more information on what the SQL Server is doing. It seems mine is not running and I'm guessing that is why I get the error. **How do I turn on my SQL server?**

```
PS C:\Users\rohrl> get-service *sql*

Status   Name               DisplayName
------   ----               -----------
Stopped  MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS   SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)
Stopped  SQLAgent$SQLEXP... SQL Server Agent (SQLEXPRESS)
Stopped  SQLBrowser         SQL Server Browser
Stopped  SQLTELEMETRY$SQ... SQL Server CEIP service (SQLEXPRESS)
Running  SQLWriter          SQL Server VSS Writer
```

Comment: Did you check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-ver15) yet?

Comment: I can’t even find out where the software is installed currently. I have 4 different folders named SQL express.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to start the services by control panel/services or by command:

```
net start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
net start "SQL Server Browser"
```

please, take a look at this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/start-stop-pause-resume-restart-sql-server-services?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @MNuschi Note the Agent service is only necessary if you're using the Agent in your server such as for scheduled jobs.

Comment: Express version does not support the agent - so no reason to attempt starting it.

Comment: Thank you @mbuschi

Answer (score 2):

You're 90% of the way there in PowerShell - just mod your command slightly:

```
get-service *sql* | start-service
```

SQL Express can't use the agent so it doesn't matter if it starts or not.

---

**PowerShell Explanation:**

PowerShell allows you to pipe the output of one command into another, so the output of `get-service` (all your services) will be passed to the `start-service` command, which will attempt to start each of these services.